# How to connect to HC05 in master role?

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my Android application I created a broadcast receiver that listens to `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` and `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED`. When the HC05 is in master role it enters those two actions one after another periodically and it never stops.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver BTReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);


        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(TAG1, device.getAddress() + "ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED");

        }

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(TAG1, device.getAddress() + "ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED");                
        }
    }
};
```

[image: Here you can see and the logs I received]

So I was wondering instead of connecting to the HC05 when it's on the slave mode and having to open the socket when my wifi is detected or another near bluetooth device is detected, i could use this to know when the HC05 is in range and then connect to it.

Comment: Do you use any method to connect to it, or you only want to handle the connection/disconnection event ?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Copy/paste a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, I tried connecting to it, with createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MyUUID) and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution broadcast receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver BTReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("Test", "DVC CON " + device.getAddress());
            if (device.getAddress().equals("98:D3:31:FB:2A:CE")) {
                BluetoothSocket socket = null;
                String data = "/0";
                byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();
                try {
                    BluetoothServerSocket bluesocketserver = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("", BTModuleUUID);
                    socket = bluesocketserver.accept();
                    if(socket.isConnected())
                        socket.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Test", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Use these commands with the presented order `AT+ROLE=1\r\n`, `AT+INIT\r\n` and `AT+BIND=<Bluetooth Address>\r\n` to receive the broadcasts. After using those commands put the HC05 module on the normal mode. The broadcasts are only received when the android device is discoverable.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. You cannot avoid these events to be triggered, because they are sent by the Android OS. This happens because your HC05 use Secure Simple Pairing (SSP) process.

If you are connected to your HC05 through `BluetoothSocket.connect()`, your phone will be connected as Slave and your HC05 as Master.

To have your phone in master role means that your HC05 have to initialize the connection and your phone has to accept the incoming connection with [listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(java.lang.String,%20java.util.UUID)).

See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer) for further informations.

Note that your phone can only have one Master and until 7 Slaves.

To solve my problem, I didn't listen for `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` and I handled the connection after calling `BluetoothSocket.connect()`.

From [BluetoothSocket.connect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#connect())

> This method will block until a connection is made or the connection fails. If this method returns without an exception then this socket is now connected.

This a sample of the Thread

```
//Thread.java
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        mSocket.connect();

        // Handle the connection here
        handleConnectedSocket(mSocket);

    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
        try {
            mSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", closeException);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

If `handleConnectedSocket()` is triggered, it means that you are successfully connected to your device.

Then I set a `boolean connected` class attribute to `true` in the above method (previously initialized to `false`), with a getter:

```
//Thread.java
private void handleConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    connected = true;
    // Manage your connection here

}

public boolean isConnected() {
    return connected;
}
```

Finally, in the `BroadcastReceiver` you can check if you were connected:

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
    // Check if we previously were connected
    if (mThread.isConnected()) {
        mThread.handleDisconnection();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: In `handleConnectedSocket()` you can pass, for exemple, the BluetoothDevice, and then follow the same process above you'll be able to do a better check in your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
    String deviceName = device.getName();

    // Check if the disconnecting device corresponds to the managed connection
    if (deviceName != null && deviceName.equals(mThread.getDeviceName())) {
        mThread.handleDisconnection();
    }
}
```

Where `getDeviceName()` is:

```
//Thread.java
@Nullable
static String getDeviceName() {
    return connected ? mDevice.getName() : null;
}
```

Comment: Why downvoting ?

Comment: Do you know how I could do this using an intent service, and still beeing able to send data using the UI ?

Comment: I never used an IntentService so I don't really know right now. To send data in the UI or update the UI you can pass the data through *broadcasted Intents* with [sendBroadcast()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) (where you can put extras in the intent)